# A custom control that embeds a TFDQuery doesn't save its persistent fields to the DFM

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I've created a custom component: it's an Entity editor: a pair of key & description TextEdits with a search option, that now I want to expand to supply a Dataset with the Data of the chosen Entity. It publishes that internal Data, a TFDQuery, as a property.

```
type
  TKpDBEntityEdit = class(TdxPanel)
  private
    ...
    procedure SetEntityData(const Value: TFDQuery);
  protected
    ...
    FEntityData: TKpQuery;
    FEntityDatasource: TDatasource;
  public
    ...
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    ...
    property EntityData: TFDQuery read FEntityData write SetEntityData;
    property EntityDatasource: TDatasource read FEntityDatasource;
end;   

implementation
...
constructor TKpDBEntityEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ...
  FEntityData := TFDQuery.Create(Self);
  FEntityData.Name := Self.Name + 'qEntity';
  FEntityData.SetSubComponent(True);
  FEntityDatasource := TDatasource.Create(Self);
  FEntityDatasource.DataSet := FEntityData;
  FEntityDatasource.Name := Self.Name + 'dsEntity';
  ...
end;

procedure TKpDBEntityEdit.SetEntityData(const Value: TFDQuery);
begin
  FEntityData.Assign(Value);
end;
```

This is the ComponentEditor that I have coded to be able to call ShowFieldsEditor and fill the persistent fields at design time:

```
unit EntityEdit.Editor;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, DesignIntf, DesignEditors;

  type
  TkpEntityEditEditor = class(TComponentEditor)
  public
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); override;
    function GetVerb(Index: Integer): string; override;
    function GetVerbCount: Integer; override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  Dialogs,
  DSDesign,
  MyDbEntityEdit;

procedure TkpEntityEditEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  case Index of
    0: ShowFieldsEditor(Designer, TKpDBEntityEdit(Component).EntityData, TDSDesigner);
  end;
end;

function TkpEntityEditEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  case Index of
    0: Result := 'Entity Fields Editor...';
  end;
end;

function TkpEntityEditEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponentEditor(TKpDbEntityEdit, TkpEntityEditEditor);
end;

end.
```

My problem is that its persistent fields are not stored in the DFM, not even after calling SetSubcomponent(True) on my internal FDQuery.

This is the DFM for adding an EntityEdit with 4 persistent fields, which are not saved, on a form.

```
object KpDBEntityEdit1: TKpDBEntityEdit2 [17]
  Left = 179
  Top = 138
  Width = 548
  Height = 21
  Frame.Borders = []
  Color = 15790320
  TabOrder = 2
  EntityName = 'TCountry'
  ShowKey = True
  ShowDescription = True
  KeyWidth = 75
end
```

Oddly enough, the form does declare those 4 persistent fields, although these declarations doesn't correspond to any object in the DFM.

```
type
  TfrmColour = class(TKpView)
    ...
    KpDBEntityEdit1: TKpDBEntityEdit2;
    KpDBEntityEdit1code: TWideStringField;
    KpDBEntityEdit1description: TWideStringField;
    KpDBEntityEdit1coating: TWideStringField;
    KpDBEntityEdit1outdated: TBooleanField;
```

What have I missed ?. Why the persistent fields that I successfully create on the internal dataset are not stored in the DFM ?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the persistent fields that I successfully create on the internal dataset are not stored in the DFM ?

Because the *Fields* of a *TDataSet* are written by calling the datasets *GetChildren* method after its properties are written, but that one is not called for a subcomponent. Only published properties of a subcomponent are written as part of the owning component.